# Split the elements in the list into separate lines with same data in list of dict

Tags: python

I want to separate the data as in the title with Python, namely is:

My data is list of dict:

```
my_list = [{"info": ["student A", "idA"], "class": "A1"},
           {"info": ["student B", "idB"], "class": "A2"}]
```

I want result is:

```
my_list = [{"info": "student A", "class": "A1"}, 
           {"info": "idA", "class": "A1"},
           {"info": "student B", "class": "A2"},
           {"info": "idB", "class": "A2"}]
```

I don't know how to solve it yet. Is there any way I can get the result?

Comment: show us what you tried ?

Comment: "I don't know how to solve it" is a bad attitude to have when you are learning something. You will find it much more productive to learn by doing something than by seeing others do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to describe *in words* what you need to do. Then draw a flowchart of the process. *Then* try to write code.

In this case, you have multiple items in `my_list`. Each item is a dictionary that contains a list of `"info"` and a single `"class"`.

You want to create a `new_item` for each `student` in `item['info']`, with the same class as `item['class']`.

```
output = [] # Empty list to hold output

for item in my_list:                  # Iterate over items in my_list
    for student in item["info"]:      # for each student 
        # create the new item
        new_item = {"info": student, "class": item["class"]}
        # append it to output
        output.append(new_item)
```

Which gives your desired output:

```
[{'info': 'student A', 'class': 'A1'},
 {'info': 'idA', 'class': 'A1'},
 {'info': 'student B', 'class': 'A2'},
 {'info': 'idB', 'class': 'A2'}]
```

Once you're more comfortable with python, you can write this as a list comprehension:

```
output = [  {"info": student, "class": item["class"]}
    for item in my_list
    for student in item["info"]
]
```

Answer (score -1):

A basic approach :

- Loop through each dictionary `my_list`
- Create 2 new dictionaries from each dictionary

  - The two dictionaries will have the same `class` but different info
- Append the 2 dictionaries to a `new_list`

```py
my_list = [{"info": ["student A", "idA"], "class": "A1"},
           {"info": ["student B", "idB"], "class": "A2"}]

new_list = []

for dic in my_list:
    info_list = dic["info"]

    # Assuming info_list has size 2
    for i in range(0, 2):
        # create new dictionary
        new_dic = {}
        new_dic["info"] = info_list[i]
        new_dic["class"] = dic["class"]
        new_list.append(new_dic)

print(new_list)

# [{'info': 'student A', 'class': 'A1'}, {'info': 'idA', 'class': 'A1'},
#  {'info': 'student B', 'class': 'A2'}, {'info': 'idB', 'class': 'A2'}]
```

Comment: `new_dic` is the same object, so that output is wrong. Putting it into a list doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Oh my bad. You're right. I fixed my mistake.

Comment: That works now, but why duplicate the code? It's simpler to loop over `info_list` instead, like in [Pranav's answer](/a/73253521/4518341).

Comment: I wanted to clearly show how two separate dictionaries are created from `dic`. However, I guess you're right. In this case, the code duplication is not worth it.